# Subarray from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, sub-array

I have a NSMutableArray with many objects.
Can i extract a subarray from index range 'i' to 'j' directly?
Yeah i know i can do a loop and use objectAtIndex:x and extract each object to a new.

I need to call a method which input is an array and want to use this array only with validate data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [subarrayWithRange:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDBFIA) method of *NSArray*.

Comment: But I want a NSMutableArray.